# TAC abbreviation

Tags: components, identification

[image]What does TAC stand for on a circuit board?

Comment: it refers to the component.  ... do a web search for the part number that is printed on the component to get your answer ... you do the search ... we have no way of guessing what the part is

Comment: I tried but label is worn. What is readable is ST technology logo the TB3560

Answer (score 2):

I would expect "TAC" stands for "TRIAC" but I have no way to confirm this 100% with the information provided. "**3560**" from ST suggests it may be the [T435-600B-TR](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/cf/95/c3/9d/a2/b7/47/43/CD00002383.pdf/files/CD00002383.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002383.pdf) 4A TRIAC. If you look at the datasheet on page 13 you'll see the package markings, one of them being "T4 **3560**" in a DPAK package. That seems to match the component in your image. I don't believe "TAC" is a standard designator though, and is probably specific to this board's manufacturer.

Comment: A triac is a form of thyristor (bidirectional triode thyristor) and according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator) the standard designator for a thyristor is "D".

Comment: @ThePhoton Same as a diode. Would have expected some sort of identifier to set the two apart though....

Comment: It looks like a series T8 triac which is all the info I need.

Comment: I was kinda surprised too. They also say "Q" is preferred for both BJTs and FETs, so this "standard" is not really the final word.

Comment: "Q" for both BJTs and FETs matches what I've seen in my experience.